# BeagleBone Black running upstream stable kernel/u-boot without any patches

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I have been exploring the BeagleBone Black (BBB) for some time now with pre-built images. Now I'm trying to get my own kernel compiled and deployed.

In that search, I found that TI has it's own repository [here](https://git.ti.com/processor-sdk/processor-sdk-linux.git) and there is another popular patch-set repository [here](https://github.com/RobertCNelson/ti-linux-kernel-dev) (and many others) both of which have some additional patches over the mainline.

I'm given to understand that BBB support for both u-boot and linux-kernel has been completely upstreamed. Shouldn't I be able to build a stable kernel/u-boot with a suitable toolchain and expect it to work on the BBB? If so, why are there so may patched repositories? If they are indeed essential for the common users, why isn't it upstreamed already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm given to understand that BBB support for both u-boot and
>   linux-kernel has been completely upstreamed.

Nothing is ever truly and fully "complete", especially in open source.

> Shouldn't I be able to
>   build a stable kernel/u-boot with a suitable toolchain and expect it
>   to work on the BBB?

**yes** - for definitions of 'stable' and 'work'.

- The vanilla Linux kernel will work absolutely stable on a genuine BBB for probably 99% of all users.
- The same goes for U-Boot.

> If so, why are there so may patched repositories?

As mentioned earlier, nothing is ever truly **done** in open source. Some aspects that are important for certain users, might for various reasons not be upstream. Those can be political reasons, priorities, or others.

> If they are indeed essential for the common users, why isn't it
>   upstreamed already?

The mere existence of downstream repositories does not imply them being essential for "common users". Actually, at this stage of the lifecycle, they are rather repositories that serve niche needs. For example, Robert Nelson's git tree contains a fairly thin patch-set that is being maintained for the benefit of a specific user group: users who expect backward compatibility to early beagleboard.org firmwares. While TI tries to maintain their SDK with certain commercial goals and may provide additional things, like the accelerated 3D graphics drivers, which are proprietary.

### It is important to realize certain concepts that apply to this space.

- There are *many* definitions of "done", "complete" and "works"
- Over time, most functionality will reach a *working* state
- Less popular or less documented hardware parts may never be *working*
- Newer hardware may require changes upstream.

  - Case in point, 4.19 is going to add support for the ["BeagleBone *enhanced*"](https://beagleboard.org/enhanced) and also U-Boot will see some changes in that regard.
- Nobody forces downstream to submit their patches upstream, on the contrary, it is most of the time significant work to get patches accepted upstream and may even necessitate rewriting large portions of code.

What I'm trying to convey is that things aren't black and white. The AM335x support in the Linux kernel actually got massive amounts of work put in to get everything that's humanly feasible upstream. In the end, you need to decide for yourself if the functionality provided by the vanilla kernel is sufficient for your use case. Only you can make that decision.

Comment: Updated question to be more specific. Thanks for pointing out, I thought it was implicit.